# Call to undefined method in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So i just want to make simple form to add, update, and delete some data(Name, id, and address). Add and delete works fine for me, but the update doesn't, codeigniter give me a error message :

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to undefined method Mahasiswa_model::getMahasiswa()
Filename: controllers/Mahasiswa.php
Line Number: 35
Backtrace:

And these is my code which i thought its related with the error.
This one file name is Mahasiswa.php

```
<?php
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('no direcet  script access allowed');

    class Mahasiswa extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->model('Mahasiswa_model');
        }

        public function index() {
            $data['mhs'] = $this->Mahasiswa_model->retrieve();
            $this->load->view('Mahasiswa_view', $data);
        }

        public function form_tambah() {
            $this->load->view('Tambah_view');
        }

        public function submit() {
            $this->Mahasiswa_model->add($this->input->post('var'));
            $data['submitted'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->view('Tambah_view', $data);
        }

        function delete() {
            $this->Mahasiswa_model->delete($this->uri->rsegment(3));
            $this->index();
        }

        function form_update() {
            $data['mhs'] = $this->Mahasiswa_model->getMahasiswa($this->uri->rsegment(3));
            $this->load->view('update_view', $data);
        }

        function update() {
            $this->Mahasiswa_model->update($this->input->post('old_nim'),
            $this->input->post('var'));
            $this->index();
        }
    }
?>
```

And this one is Mahasiswa_model.php

```
<?php
    class Mahasiswa_model extends CI_Model {
        function retrieve() {
            $query = $this->db->get('mhs');

            if($query->result()) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $content) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        $content->nim,
                        $content->nama,
                        $content->alamat
                    );
                }
                return $data;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        function add($arg) {
            $data = array (
                'nim' => $arg[0],
                'nama'=> $arg[1],
                'alamat' => $arg[2],
            );

            $this->db->insert('mhs', $data);
        }

        function delete($id) {
            $this->db->where('nim', $id);
            $this->db->delete('mhs');
        }

        function update($id, $form) {
            $data = array(
                'nim' => $form[0],
                'nama' =>$form[1],
                'alamat' => $form[2],
            );
        }
    }
?>
```

Maybe someone can help me find where mistake i made? Line 35 not clear enough for me

Comment: `$this->getMahasiswa` <-  this method is not declared in your controller

Comment: i've tried removed it, but it gave me another error

Comment: again there is no method in your model. Please ensure that you have added correct code

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll give it a try

Comment: i thought `getMahasiswa` taken from the same file at line 4 `class Mahasiswa extends CI_Controller` is it?

Answer (score 1):

This line in your controller is the problem:

`$this->Mahasiswa_model->getMahasiswa($this->uri->rsegment(3));`

You're calling the getMahasiswa method that should be available in your model, but (assuming the code you posted for your model is complete) it's not. Your model only has the `retrieve`, `add`, `delete` and `update` methods declared.

you either need to create the `getMahasiswa` method in your model, or you need to call a different method from your controller.

if you want to call a function from same controller then simply write.

`$data = $this->getMahasiswa($parameter1)`; 
IMP : function must be present there in the same controller.

Comment: Honestly those codes from my college module, i dont know am i written those code wrong or is my module, but thanks for the algorythm.